# lazy loading/running text did change for uisearchbar in xcode

Tags: xcode, searchbar

I have a searchbar and searchbar controller that displays parsed xml in a UItableview with any character change in  the searchbar field. THe problem lies in speed.

CUrrently, it takes a while to contanstly get an xml file and parse it while entering the search bar text.

Is there any way to optimize this? Like lazy load the tableview after searching and parsing the searchbar text after the word entry hasen been entered.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using [NSOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSOperation).

Keep the model data in a location separate from the table data source. I usually use something like `@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *data` for the model data and `@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tableData` for the data currently displayed in the table. In `-searchBar:textDidChange:`, cancel the previous search operation, reset tableData empty, start a new search operation. The operation would perform the search and add results to tableData.

For a better user experience, instead of resetting the tableData to empty with each new character. You could simply remove items that don't match the new search string before starting the search operation. Of course, you would need to make sure the operation doesn't add items into tableData that are already in it.